# How do I scale tables to window? Do I need CSS and/or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I've been attempting to create a table inside one of my divs, one that adjust it's width when the windows scales or resolution changes. However, the tables keep bleeding through whenever the screen changes

Is it as simple as using CSS to achieve it, or is it something more complicated that I'm missing.

```
    <img  align='left' src='http://imgur.com/e8K63LI.png'></img>
        <table bordercolor='black' width='900' bgcolor='white' border='0'>
            <tr>
                <td align='left'> <h1>XTR 250LC</h1> </td>
            </tr>
                <td align='right'><b>Price to be determined</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h3>Specs</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Available Colors</b></td><td>White, Blue and Black</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Curb Weight</b></td><td>223 lbs</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: that behavior is typical to table (html or displayed as via css) it expands or shrink according to its content. table-layout:fixed; can force width if specified

Comment: I tried the table-layout:fixed as you suggested, but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fixed width on your table tag:

```
<table bordercolor='black' bgcolor='white' border='0'>
```

You can add "width: 100%" style. This way it'll change its size when the resolution changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I applied `.tableclass{width: 100%;}` and then `<table class='tableclass' bordercolor='black' bgcolor='white' border='0'>`, but still got the stretching issue